# factory with additional optional parameterrs

Tags: php, design-patterns, factory, builder

I have the following factory class, which takes as a parameter a value `$type` based on which it creates a different class, and some additional optional parameters, which are passed only to the class that needs them.

```
class OptionalParametersDto extends DataTransferObject
{
       public ?bool $someValue = null;
       public ?string $someString = null;      
}
```

Both `ClassA` and `ClassB`  expect in the constructor an instance of `OptionalParametersDto`.

```
class A{
       public function __construct(OptionalParametersDto $parameters){}
}

class B{
       public function __construct(OptionalParametersDto $parameters){}
}
```

```
class Factory
{
       public function create(string $type, array $optionalParameters)
       {
                 if($type === 'A'){
                      return new ClassA(new OptionalParametersDto(['someValue' => $optionalParameters['someValue']]));
                 }
                 if($type === 'B'){
                      return new ClassB(new OptionalParametersDto());
                 }
        }
}
```

it seems that the factory pattern is being abused when it needs to know which parameters need to be passed to each class.

Also passing a dto that might have fields that one class needs, but the other class does not need, looks like a code smell.

Is there a more elegant way to do this ?

Comment: How about making a factory class for each of the underlying classes you want to create? Any commonalities between these factory classes can be inherited from a parent factory class.

Comment: that is an option of course, just trying to figure out what is the best balance between simplicity and functionality, because creating a factory for each class adds complexity. So i want to see if the current solution can be considered ok, or if it should be avoided and try something different, like creating a factory for each class like you suggested.

Comment: I somewhat understand your objections, but calling my proposal more "complex" isn't correct. Creating separate factory classes isn't all that complex, trying to create one for all of them is. You probably can/should also combine some factory classes without the problems you described, leaving you with tailor made factory classes that are simpler, and more specific, than the one you're creating now. I have to point out that your question is quite abstract, more theoretical, while at the same time it sounds like you are already committed to a certain path of action.

Comment: i am open to any suggestion, nothing is finalized yet. Maybe i didn't choose the right words, i meant that one option is to include all the details in one factory class, and the alternative ( which i don't think is bad ) is to create more classes. I am taking also the size of the current solution into account, which is small. So i am thinking, should i go KISS because we are talking for a couple of optional parameters, or should i be strict and follow solid principles, and create a separate factory for each.

Comment: just to clarify, are those optional parameters static or can change at runtime?

Comment: they are set only once when the instance of the class is created and they won't change again.

Comment: understood, but my question was more on "where are those values coming from". Are they know beforehand (eg. you read them from a config file) or do they change at runtime somehow?

If they're somehow known, you can use DI to inject them into your factory's ctor instead of passing them as parameters to the create() method.